# One Drive Error in Sign In with GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am trying to Sign In with GraphServiceClient, but during the attempt, I have this error message: **OneDrive reported the following error: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server or proxy was not found.**
[Error en Sign In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OuGv.png)
The code I got from the sample is this:

```
public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient(){
    if (graphClient == null)            {
        // Create Microsoft Graph client.
        try {
            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                var token = await GetTokenForUserAsync();
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new 
                AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token); }));
                return graphClient;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return graphClient;
    }
```

Comment: The error occurs because the port that is used is blocked by the firewall